# std::array equivalent in C

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I'm new to C and C++, and I've read that at least in C++ it's preferable to use std::array or std::vector when using vectors and arrays, specially when passing these into a function.

In my research I found the following, which makes sense. I suppose using std::vector would fix the problem of indexing outside of the variable's scope.

> ```
> void foo(int arr[10]) { arr[9] = 0; }
>
> void bar() {
>     int data[] = {1, 2};
>     foo(data);
> }
> ```
>
> The above code is wrong but the compiler thinks everything is fine and
>   issues no warning about the buffer overrun.
>
> Instead use std::array or std::vector, which have consistent value
>   semantics and lack any 'special' behavior that produces errors like
>   the above.

(answer from bames53, thanks btw!)

What I want to code is

```
float foo(int X, int Y, int l){
    // X and Y are arrays of length l
    float z[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i ++){
        z[i] = X[i]+Y[i];
    }
    return z;
}

int bar(){
    int l = 100;
    int X[l];
    int Y[l];
    float z[l];
    z = foo(X,Y,l);
    return 0;
}
```

I want this to be coded in C, so my question is is there a std::vector construct for C? I couldn't find anything on that.

Thanks in advance, also please excuse my coding (I'm green as grass in C and C++)

Comment: >is there a `std::vector` construct for C?
Nope, you would have to implement it yourself or use a library for it. C has no containers included with it except the arrays and pointers.

Comment: C or C++ standards don't allow variable based allocated arrays on the stack. With c you'll need to go for some `malloc()` solution, in c++ you'll use `std::vector`.

Comment: C and C++ are *different* languages. Don't believe that knowing C++ helps with C or vice versa. Decide what you want to learn first. BTW C++ is a *very* complex language, and you might consider learning e.g. [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/) or [Go](http://golang.org/) instead. Both are considerably easier than C++. C++ is complex because of legacy

Comment: @N00byEdge I see... Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a reason that you seek for `std::vector`-like thing in C? Why don't you use C++ instead? If you're a beginner, you definitely want to learn C++, not C. You should only go with C, if you have a strong reason for that.

Comment: Your code is too mangled to understand even as pseudo code, you pass an array to an `int` and then comment that the `int` denotes size? Anyway, there is no `std::vector` analogue in standard C.

Comment: @geza I'm only looking to implement some custom extensions for python (I know for the above there are plenty of python modules that will work better than anything I can write... but I still thought it may be useful for other custom functions I may need in multiple scripts and if not useful at the very least entertaining)

Comment: @LDN: I think that you can create extensions for python in C++ too, so there's no reason to use C for that. C++ is a much more advanced language than C, so as I've said, I'd only use C if there's a strong reason for that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually variable-length arrays are supported in C99 (and optional in C11). So you don't need `malloc` there for small enough arrays.

Comment: *"Instead use std::array or std::vector ... lack any 'special' behavior that produces errors like the above"* - `std::vector` and `std::array` allow you to access out-of-bounds, too. `vector's` `operator[]` does not perform bounds checking. I think you need to use [`vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) to perform bounds checking and get the exception or error you are looking for. I don't recall what happens with `std::array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard C has nothing like `std::vector` or other container structures. All you get is built-in arrays and `malloc`.

> I suppose using std::vector would fix the problem of indexing outside of the variable's scope.

You might think so, but you'd be wrong: Indexing outside of the bounds of a `std::vector` is just as bad as with a built-in array. The `operator[]` of `std::vector` doesn't do any bounds checking either (or at least it is not guaranteed to). If you want your index operations checked, you need to use `arr.at(i)` instead of `arr[i]`.

Also note that code like

```
float z[l];
...
return z;
```

is wrong because there are no array values in C (or C++, for that matter). When you try to get the value of an array, you actually get a pointer to its first element. But that first element (and all other elements, and the whole array) is destroyed when the function returns, so this is a classic use-after-free bug: The caller gets a dangling pointer to an object that doesn't exist anymore.

The customary C solution is to have the caller deal with memory allocation and pass an output parameter that the function just writes to:

```
void foo(float *z, const int *X, const int *Y, int l){
    // X and Y are arrays of length l
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i ++){
        z[i] = X[i]+Y[i];
    }
}
```

That said, there are some libraries that provide dynamic data structures for C, but they necessarily look and feel very different from C++ and `std::vector` (e.g. I know about [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html)).

Comment: Thanks! I was just coding this and I realised what you're saying about passing the output parameter to the function. I just changed it and had Y be the output. (i.e. Y[i] = X[i] + Y[i]). From the responses to my question I also gather I should probably just code in C++ for my extensions if anything. Still was an interesting excercise. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be sensitive for some programmers of the language.
Using constructs of one language into another can be considered cursing as different languages have different design decisions.

C++ and C share a huge part, in a way that C code can (without a lot of modifications) be compiled as C++. However, if you learn to master C++, you will realize that a lot of strange things happen because how C works.

Back to the point: C++ contains a standard library with containers as `std::vector`. These containers make use of several C++ constructions that ain't available in C:

- RAII (the fact that a Destructor gets executed when the instance goes out-of-scope) will prevent a memory leak of the allocated memory
- Templates will allow type safety to not mix doubles, floats, classes ...
- Operator overloading will allow different signatures for the same function (like erase)
- Member functions

None of these exist in C, so in order to have a similar structure, several adaptions are required for getting a data structure that behaves almost the same.

In my experience, most C projects have their own generic version of data structures, often based on `void*`. Often this will look similar like:

```
 struct Vector
 {
      void *data;
      long  size;
      long  capacity;
 };

 Vector *CreateVector()
 {
      Vector *v = (Vector *)(malloc(sizeof(Vector)));
      memset(v, 0, sizeof(Vector));
      return v;
 }

 void DestroyVector(Vector *v)
 {
      if (v->data)
      {
          for (long i = 0; i < v->size; ++i)
              free(data[i]);
          free(v->data);
      }
      free(v);
 }

 // ...
```

Alternatively, you could mix C and C++.

```
 struct Vector
 {
      void *cppVector;
 };

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

 Vector CreateVector()
 void DestroyVector(Vector v)

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
```

vectorimplementation.cpp

```
 #include "vector.h"

 struct CDataFree
 {
       void operator(void *ptr) { if (ptr) free(ptr); }
 };
 using CData = std::unique_ptr<void*, CDataFree>;

 Vector CreateVector()
 {
      Vector v;
      v.cppVector = static_cast<void*>(std::make_unique<std::vector<CData>>().release());
      return v;
 }

 void DestroyVector(Vector v)
 {
      auto cppV = static_cast<std::vector<CData>>(v.cppVector);
      auto freeAsUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<CData>>(cppV);
 }

 // ...
```

Comment: I see... I don't mean to be disrespectful with my ignorance.
I really appreciate all the feedback and I will learn from it. I'll also study this code. Thanks!!

Comment: @Storyteller: I no longer write new. For delete, I clean it the same as created

Comment: What is the point of re-writing a `Vector` class in C++? When I first scanned the code I thought it was for C which makes for sense. Then I saw the C++ and thought, WTF?

Comment: @jww The question is about exposing a vector class in C

Comment: Here was the question: *"I want this to be coded in C, so my question is is there a std::vector construct for C?"* He is working in C, and he needs the `Vector`-like data type with the external functions like `CreateVector`, `DestroyVector` and probably some setters and getters. None of the other stuff makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

The closest equivalent of `std::array` in c is probably a preprocessor macro defintion like

```
#define ARRAY(type,name,length) \
     type name[(length)]
```